# Is a subquery, which is returning no row, equal to NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In SQL Server, if my `SELECT` statement in a subquery returns no row, is then the result of the subquery equal to `NULL`? I made some research, but I am not sure about it.

Example:

```
IF (SELECT TOP 1 CLMN1 FROM SOMETABLE) IS NOT NULL THEN
   ....
```

I am asking to understand the behaviour of the if-statement above.

Comment: You can always try it and find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL means no value, for example that the "box" for a certain column in a certain row is empty. NO ROW means that there are no rows.

Comment: so, if it doesnt return any row, it doesnt mean it returns null

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ: Correct. No rows is not the same as null.

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ indeed! In layman terms, it's the difference between "an empty box" and "no box at all"

Comment: Actually, AFAIK, null doesn't mean `no value`, but `unknown value`. It's demonstrated by the fact that `null = null` is always false.

Comment: It is a bit dubious, but the statement is correct. You try to retrieve the first value of the column CLM1 from the table, so it does not return a row, but a single value. If there are no results than this will be a NULL value. As I said not the best way to do it, but it should work.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the answer is yes:

```
 DECLARE @Test TABLE (Id INT)
 INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1)

 SELECT * FROM @Test WHERE Id = 2
 SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT * FROM @Test WHERE Id = 2) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

EDIT: after you updated your question I think I should add that instead of checking if there are rows with IS NULL you should use the following that can be  better optimised by the server:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Test WHERE Id = 2)
BEGIN
   -- Whatever
END
```

Comment: +1 -- Wow, I had not thought of the question in this way (prior to the edit), but you are correct that SQL Server treats an empty result set as a NULL in a comparison test.  Note that constructs like this are very dangerous as if you get more than 1 row back you'll get the dreaded "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error...

Answer (score 2):

No, `NULL` is a column value that indicates that the value of that column for a given row has no valid value.  There would have to be a row returned by your query for that row to contain `NULL` column values.

A query that returns no rows just means that no rows matched the predicate you used in the query and therefore no data was returned at all.

Edit:  After the question was edited, my answer doesn't address the specific case called out in the question.  Juan's answer above does.